I've got 502 Bad Gateway errors only in customer login and account registration
Both
customer/account/loginPost/referer/....... &
/customer/account/createpost/
Lead to 502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Interesting fact is that customers actually are able to create account (as i am not requiring email verification at the moment).
But they are unable to login.
That's start happen once i set my base url to https - if it's any connection.
Is there anything more that should be done to allow my customers to login in their accounts?
I am ready to provide more information just ask what will help to investigate the root of that issue.
Thanks.

Check the magento log file as well, is there any error during this action?

Found the solution in other post: It was just needed to insert in nginx.conf file the following: fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
